# How to render nested list in HTML from JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, html, json, parsing, object

I have an object, which looks like this:

```js
let obj = {
  name: "name1",
  nest: [
    {
      name: "name2",
      nest: [
        {
          name: "name3"
        },
        {
          name: "name4",
          nest: [
            {
              name: "name5",
              nest: [
                {
                  name: "name6"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              name: "name7"
            },
            {
              name: "name8"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

let parent = document.querySelector("ul");

function forOf (obj) {
 for (let key in obj) {
  if ( typeof obj[key] === "object" && obj.hasOwnProperty("nest") ) {
   createList(obj[name], obj[key]);
  } else if ( typeof obj[key] !== "object" ) {
   let item = document.createElement("li");
   item.textContent = obj[key];
   parent.appendChild(item);
  } else {
   forOf(obj[key]);
  }
 }
}

function createList(obj, skills) {
 let item = document.createElement("ul");
 item.textContent = obj;
 parent.appendChild(item);
 parent = item;
 forOf(skills);
}

forOf(obj);
```

I need to render tree of nested unordered lists. I parsed my object, but I can't render it in right way. I can't resolve problem with parent item for every nested list. Maybe, you have any ideas how to fix it?

I want to get result like this: [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjuI6.png)

Comment: Please be more specific about your desired behavior, how that differs from what you are getting, and what you've tried so far.

Comment: Yes, of course: desired behavior is proper rendering of nested lists, with different levels of nesting. Like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjuI6.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a single loop with just the defined keys for the value and the nest array as children.

```js
function createList(parent, array) {
    array.forEach(function (o) {
        var li = document.createElement("li"),
            ul;

        li.textContent = o.name;
        parent.appendChild(li);
        if (o.nest) {
            ul = document.createElement("ul");
            li.appendChild(ul);
            createList(ul, o.nest);
        }
    });
}

var  object = { name: "name1", nest: [{ name: "name2", nest: [{ name: "name3" }, { name: "name4", nest: [{ name: "name5", nest: [{ name: "name6" }] }, { name: "name7" }, { name: "name8" }] }] }] }

createList(document.querySelector("ul"), [object]);
```

```html
<ul></ul>
```